# Ember Simple Auth Devise Authenticator Failing

Tags: ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I'm attempting to set up a new ember app, and I'm trying to set up ESA to integrate with devise.

I'm following the walkthrough with the exception of using the devise authenticator

```
@action 
async authenticate() {
  let { identification, password } = this;
  try { 
    await this.session.authenticate('authenticator:devise', identification, password);
  } catch (error) {
    this.errorMessage = error.error || error
  }
}
```

What I'm seeing on the call to session.authenticate is an error during lookup authenticator with setting some unknown ember property

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '__OWNER__ember1589293697731192541050875__' of undefined
    at Object.setOwner (index.js:80)
    at Proxy._lookupAuthenticator (internal-session.js:228)
    at Proxy.authenticate (internal-session.js:31)
    at Class.authenticate (session.js:168)
    at LoginController.authenticate (login.js:44)
```

It doesn't even get to the point of calling out to the backend to authenticate, and identification and password are set, and I can't find anything I'm doing wrong with the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the repo or a minimal reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I missed a step in the walkthrough where I needed to make a local app/authenticators folder and extend the devise authenticator inside of that. Back on track!